# How transform a string in a bidimensonal array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I have to convert/transform a "string of values" in a "bidimensional array".

String structure

```
original=LatLng(46.20467, 13.34764),LatLng(46.20467, 13.34767),LatLng(46.20467, 13.34772),LatLng(46.20469, 13.34782),LatLng(46.20471, 13.34786),LatLng(46.20492, 13.34842),LatLng(46.20499, 13.34865),LatLng(46.20502, 13.34888),LatLng(46.20502, 13.34909),LatLng(46.205, 13.34953),LatLng(46.20503, 13.34969),LatLng(46.20516, 13.34992),LatLng(46.20572, 13.35065),LatLng(46.20576, 13.35075),LatLng(46.20576, 13.3508),LatLng(46.20573, 13.35092),LatLng(46.20565, 13.35101)...
```

Array structure will be

```
LatLong_completo = [[46.20467, 13.34764],[46.20467, 13.34767],[46.20467, 13.34772],[46.20469, 13.34782],[46.20471, 13.34786],[46.20492, 13.34842],[46.20499, 13.34865],[46.20502, 13.34888],[46.20502, 13.34909],[46.205, 13.34953],[46.20503, 13.34969],[46.20516, 13.34992],[46.20572, 13.35065],[46.20576, 13.35075],[46.20576, 13.3508],[46.20573, 13.35092],[46.20565, 13.35101],[46.20523, 13.35124],[46.20515, 13.35132]...
```

Actually I succesfully done it, using following code:

```
sentences = original.replace(/['LatLng(']/g, ""); // remove LatLng(
sentences = sentences.replace(/[')']/g, "");      // remove )
sentences = sentences.replace(/[' ']/g, "");      // remove (
sentences += ',';                                 // add , at the end

LatLong_base = new Array;
LatLong_completo = new Array;

// loop based on var length
for(i=0;i<sentences.length;i++){

//estrae Latitudine e Longitudine ed elimina i dati appena estratti
position = sentences.search(/,/); // find first comma in string
let Latitudine = sentences.substr(0, position); // using search result extract data
sentences = sentences.slice(position+1);       // using search remove extracted data

position = sentences.search(/,/);
let Longitudine = sentences.substr(0, position);
sentences = sentences.slice(position+1);

// assegna i dati in formato numerico all'Array

 LatLong_base.push(Number(Latitudine)); // 1st data (with number conversion) to array
 LatLong_base.push(Number(Longitudine));// 2nd data (with number conversion) to array

// assegna il nuovo array all'array principale

 LatLong_completo.push( LatLong_base); // dummy array to main array

// reset dummy array
LatLong_base=[]

}
```

Exist a best and fast solution?

Comment: is that chatGPT code?

Comment: Why do you thing, code was generated using chatGPT? I know, that is not a great code, but is best I could create by myself.

Comment: because comments verbosity level seems to be set to "exteme": ```// remove )```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `LatLng(` and `)` with brackets (`[ ]`) then parse the string as JSON.  Here is an example:

```js
let original = "LatLng(46.20467, 13.34764),LatLng(46.20467, 13.34767),LatLng(46.20467, 13.34772),LatLng(46.20469, 13.34782),LatLng(46.20471, 13.34786),LatLng(46.20492, 13.34842),LatLng(46.20499, 13.34865),LatLng(46.20502, 13.34888),LatLng(46.20502, 13.34909),LatLng(46.205, 13.34953),LatLng(46.20503, 13.34969),LatLng(46.20516, 13.34992),LatLng(46.20572, 13.35065),LatLng(46.20576, 13.35075),LatLng(46.20576, 13.3508),LatLng(46.20573, 13.35092),LatLng(46.20565, 13.35101)"

let LatLong_completo = JSON.parse('[' + original.replaceAll('LatLng(', '[').replaceAll(')', ']') + ']')

console.log(LatLong_completo)
```

Comment: This solution is exactly what I need and fits in my project. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I would use:

It splits up the string into individual strings then iterates through the strings and performs a reg expression to matches two patterns that are within brackets e.g. ([this],[and this]).

It then pushes these into the results array

```
let original = "LatLng(46.20467, 13.34764),LatLng(46.20467, 13.34767),LatLng(46.20467, 13.34772)";

// Split the string into individual LatLng strings
let latLngStrings = original.split(',');

// Initialize an empty array to store the result
let LatLong_completo = [];

// Iterate through the latLngStrings
latLngStrings.forEach((latLngString) => {
    // Extract the coordinates from the string
    let matches = latLngString.match(/\((.*),\s(.*)\)/);
    if (matches) {
        let lat = parseFloat(matches[1]);
        let lng = parseFloat(matches[2]);
        
        // Create a sub-array and push it to the resultArray
        LatLong_completo.push([lat, lng]);
    }
});

console.log(LatLong_completo);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it

```js
const original = "LatLng(46.20467, 13.34764),LatLng(46.20467, 13.34767),LatLng(46.20467, 13.34772),LatLng(46.20469, 13.34782),LatLng(46.20471, 13.34786),LatLng(46.20492, 13.34842),LatLng(46.20499, 13.34865),LatLng(46.20502, 13.34888),LatLng(46.20502, 13.34909),LatLng(46.205, 13.34953),LatLng(46.20503, 13.34969),LatLng(46.20516, 13.34992),LatLng(46.20572, 13.35065),LatLng(46.20576, 13.35075),LatLng(46.20576, 13.3508),LatLng(46.20573, 13.35092),LatLng(46.20565, 13.35101)";

//  a regex that matches a decimal number
const pattern = /(\d+\.?\d+)/g;

//  split the string on "LatLng"
const completo = original.split("LatLng").map(token => {
  //  capture each decimal string and cast to a number
  return [...token.matchAll(pattern)].map(arr => Number(arr[0]));
}).filter(arr => {
  //  remove invalid regex results
  return arr.length;
})

document.querySelector("code").innerText = JSON.stringify(completo, null, 2);
```

```css
code {
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px; 
}
```

```html
<pre><code></code></pre>
```